# counting occurrence of numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am stack for a while . I tried debugging but I couldn't figure out the solution. I am trying to count the occurrence of numbers. So my problem is that when I print the output it is

```
3 occurs 1 times
1 occurs 1 times
0 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 1 times
1 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 2 times
0 occurs 2 times
10 occurs 1 times
4 occurs 1 times
```

instead of

```
1 occurs 2 times
0 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 2 time
10 occurs 1 times
4 occurs 1 times
```

so if the number has more than 1 occurrence it should say it only once not as many times as there is occurrences. Cheers Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;

public class CountingOccuranceOfNumbers
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        countNumbers();
    }

    public static void countNumbers()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        int[] list = new int[11];
        int[] counts = new int[150];
        int counter = 0;
        int number = 1;


        while(counter <= 10)
        {
                number = generator.nextInt(11);
                list[counter] = number;
                counter++;
        }   
        for(int i=0; i<list.length - 1; i++)
        {
            counts[list[i]]++;
//          System.out.print(list[i] + " ");

            System.out.println(list[i] +" occurs " +  counts[list[i]] + " times");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you review your notes, and the course text.  The hints will be found there.  As for being stuck and asking for help on SO.  Explain exactly where you are stuck, what you tried, why it did not work.  Then add a specific question.  But review your notes first.

Comment: In case anyone couldn't tell, this was originally a homework problem, so some of the answers that you see below will reflect people trying to give the original poster hints instead of just giving him/her a complete solution. Please don't downvote those. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/163250).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is guava's Multiset classes, which will track the count for you:

```
int values[] = ...;
Multiset<Integer> ms = HashMultiset.create();
ms.addAll(Ints.asList(list));

int count0 = ms.count(Integer.valueOf(0));
int count1 = ms.count(Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Here, Multiset, HashMultiset and Ints are all guava classes.

Note that Multiset does pretty much what someone mentioned above by using a Map and counter to track the counters.  It's just abstracted away from you to make your code simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HashMap<Integer>,<integer> ht` to manage your counts

```
if (ht.get(newNumber) == null) {
     ht.put(newNumber, 1); 
} else {
     ht.put(newNumber, ++ht.get(newNumber));
}
```

*Corrected `HashTable` in `HashMap` and `++` before `get(..)`*

Comment: For the problem he has, an array is the best collection (and a Hashtable wouldn't solve his problem) Even if it did, a HashMap (as its not synchronised) or TreeMap (as its sorted) would be a better choice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey your right, I thank to Map and write Table, I correct my post

Answer (score 2):

You have one loop to count the occurrence which also give a running total. It appears what you wanted is to only print the total when the counting is finish. i.e. it should be in another loop.

Comment: should the other loop be nested or independent of this one

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll try to give you a hint or two.

1. Since you get several lines printed for each number that occurs more than once, you probably shouldn't print anything until you are done with your counting.
2. It looks like your output should be sorted after number of occurences. If this is the case, saving the counts in an array probably isn't the best idea. Consider using a `Map<Integer, Integer>` instead, where the key is the number, and the value is the number of occurences.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;


    public class NumberRepetition {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int size;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("enter size of array");
    size=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int el;
    int[] a=new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        el=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        a[i]=el;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                int temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;

            }
        }
    }
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==a[j])
            {
                count++;

            }



        }
        System.out.println(a[i]+" \t " +"occurence time is"+"\t"+count);
        if(count!=0)
        {
            i=i+count-1;
        }
        count=0;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Format your code so it is easier to read and providing informations with it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap and put new Entry in the map with key,value where value is Integer.

if you come across with same char, then increment the integer value associated with that key.
o.w it is a new key and set the value to 1.

```
Integer entryValue;
Map map = new HashMap();


    for ( int i =0; i < s1.length(); i++)
    {
        entryValue = (Integer)map.get(s1.charAt(i));

        if (entryValue == null)
        {
            map.put(s1.charAt(i), new Integer(1));
        }

        else
        {
                map.put(s1.charAt(i), new Integer(entryValue.intValue()+1));
        }
    }
```