# Java HashMap to count array entries

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

How could I use a HashMap to count the number of unique entries in this array:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Entry {

    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public void userInput(){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please tell me the amount of numbers you will be entering (Up to 50): ");
        int [] arr = new int[scan.nextInt()];      

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++) {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            while(scan.hasNextInt()){
            int x = scan.nextInt();
            arr[i]= x;
            break;
            }
        }        

         System.out.println(" ");
         System.out.println("Results of Data Entry");
         System.out.println("_____________________");
         for(int i:arr){System.out.println(i + " occurs "); 
        }
} 
}
```

I would like to output to show the number that was entered, and the amount of times it was entered.

So if I entered 1 5 6 6 7

It would show

```
1 occurs 1
5 occurs 1
6 occurs 2
7 occurs 1
```

Comment: The answer to that question tells me nothing.

Comment: For god sake, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11608757/180100) from the already linked question

Comment: You don't have to do  scan = new Scanner(System.in); two times. Just once is enough.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper function of countOccurences is like:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countOccurences (int[] arr) {
    int len = arr.length;
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int key = arr[i];
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            int value = map.get(key);
            map.put(key, value + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(key, 1);
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

The above code is supposed to be easy to read, please let me know if you need explaination.

The complete code is shown below, please pay attention to how the Hashmap is iterated:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        userInput();
    }

    public static void userInput() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Please tell me the amount of numbers you will be entering (Up to 50): ");
        int[] arr = new int[scan.nextInt()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                int x = scan.nextInt();
                arr[i] = x;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Results of Data Entry");
        System.out.println("_____________________");

        Map<Integer, Integer> counts = countOccurences (arr);

        Iterator itr = counts.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " occurs " + pairs.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> countOccurences (int[] arr) {
        int len = arr.length;
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int key = arr[i];
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                int value = map.get(key);
                map.put(key, value + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(key, 1);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works!  Is there a way to do it without using public static?

Comment: In your original question, you could just add the function private Map<Integer, Integer> countOccurences (int[] arr) to your Entity class without using public static.

Answer (score 5):

```
List asList = Arrays.asList(array);
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(asList);
for(String s : mySet) {
    System.out.println(s + " " + Collections.frequency(asList, s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. You will get what you want

```
'public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int cnt=1;
        Integer a;

        Integer arr[] = {1,2,2,3,1,4,5,3,3,3};
        Map hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            a=(Integer) hm.put(arr[i], cnt);    
            if(a!=null)
            {
                hm.put(arr[i],a+1);
            }
        }
            Set set = hm.entrySet();
          // Get an iterator
            Iterator it = set.iterator();
          // Display elements
            while(it.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
             System.out.print(me.getKey() + " occurs ");
             System.out.println(me.getValue());
            }
        }'
```

put(K,V) method of Map Interface returns the previous value for same key and null if the key is set first time.