# Won't skip if number already exists in array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am currently trying to make a method, that displays the amount of times, a number exists within a array.

My method is:

```
public void freq(int[] arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        String output = "";
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (this.helper(arr[i]) == true) {
                i++;
            } else if (this.helper(arr[i]) == false) {
               for (int k : arr) {
                    if (k == arr[i]) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Number of instances to: " + arr[i] + " : " + count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

The helper class is used to check if the number it's about to check, already has been checked. I am using a arraylist to store the numbers that are already checked:

```
private List<Integer> existingInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The method helper is written:

```
public boolean helper(int i) {
    boolean alreadyExists = false;
    for (int k : existingInt) {
        if (i == k) {
            alreadyExists = true;
            return alreadyExists;
        } else {
            existingInt.add(i);
            alreadyExists = false;
            return alreadyExists;
        }
    }
    return alreadyExists;
}
```

Helper returns a boolean, true or false, if the number exists. I thereafter check, in a if statement, if it returns true or false. If true, then i skip (or atleast try to) with:

```
if (this.helper(arr[i]) == true) {
    i++;
}
```

**In short, my method counts the number of occurances in a array of integers. What it doesn't do, is skip the check, if my helper method returns a true.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting occurrence of numbers in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608515/counting-occurrence-of-numbers-in-array)

Comment: @StephenP Yes and No. He wants to know where the error in his code is. Not how to count occurrences in arrays in special though he's implementing such a method. Possible a better place would be [SE codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Zabuza but SE codereview has informed me in the past that they don't want buggy code to debug, they want working code to review for improvements.

Comment: If you've already sorted the array I don't see the reason behind keeping track of which ones have been counted already. Get one, count until you come to a different number. Then do it again, and again, until you're done.

Comment: Editorially, `helper` is a _terrible_ name for a method — the name doesn't describe what or how it is "helping". Also, you never need to compare `== false` or `!= true` etc. If the method were named `contains(int i)` you could write `if ( ! contains(arr[i]) ) { ...`

Comment: @StephenP Couldn't agree with you more. Although this was a early model of the code, I'll definately work on the naming of my future functions, whenever I post a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're sorting the array you could do this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
        int count = 1;
        int num = arr[i];
        while(++i < arr.length && arr[i] == num) {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of instances to: " + num + " : " + count);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `return alreadyExists;` from the else part. It automatically returns false if the first item isn't i.

Edit: your method is unnecessarily complex. You can just use this:

```
public boolean helper(int i) {
    for (int k : existingInt) {
        if (i == k) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    existingInt.add(i);
    return false;
}
```

Even better, you can use a HashSet:

```
private HashSet<Integer> existingInt = new HashSet<Integer>();

public boolean helper(int i) {
    return existingInt.add(i);
}
```

Comment: I tried redoing the method, where alreadyExists would be false, and only changed if the number exists(alreadyExists = true). Still the same outcome.

Picture for reference:

http://i.imgur.com/leT6fDM.png

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: You suggest minor refactoring but not a problem solution.

Comment: Actually, the first helper method in the edit is the solution of the problem.

Comment: I tried running the code, but somehow, it doesn't do anything. The only output I get is:

http://i.imgur.com/hiJDgso.png

And I used the following code, in my main method:
    arrayTests ar = new arrayTests();
    int[] arrayTemp = {2, 5, 2, 9, 7, 1, 100, 2, 3, 5, 77, 9, 1, 2, 6, 5};
    ar.freq(arrayTemp);

Comment: Yes, because you moved `add` statement and didn't explain why

Comment: @William: I also checked your freq method. Instead of calling helper in else if, you should just use an else. You will never execute the else if block, as calling helper a second time with the same value will always return true.

Comment: @uoyilmaz Actually solved most of my issues, thank you so much. Only issue I am having now is that the number 77 isnt being displayed from my array.

Answer (score 1):

You can count occurrences by keeping track of the numbers found in a Map, as the map keys, and incrementing the map *value* as the count of how many times the number appeared.

The only trick is putting the number in the map the first time you find that number.

I use a `SortedMap`, implemented by a `TreeMap`, so the numbers will come out sorted in ascending order when getting the [keySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet()), for nice output.

This is a complete Class with a test `main` that can be compiled and run in the default package:

```
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Counter
{
    public void printFreq(final int[] numbers)
    {
        // Use a sorted map so our output is ascending.
        final SortedMap<Integer, Integer> numCounts = new TreeMap<>();

        // Count occurrences in the provided numbers
        for (final Integer i : numbers)
        {
            Integer count = numCounts.get(i);   // Get the current count
            if (count == null) count = 0;       // or init it to zero if there isn't one
            numCounts.put(i, ++count);          // Increment count and put it (back) in the map
        }

        // Output the counts
        for (final Integer n : numCounts.keySet())
        {
            System.out.printf("%d : %d\n", n, numCounts.get(n));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Counter c = new Counter();
        final int[] nums = { 3, 8, 1, 3, 12, 1, 3, 42, 12, 8 };
        c.printFreq(nums);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great looking code, does the job aswell. The code works perfect with my array, and displays the correct output. However, since this is homework, I would have to use the code I originally had a issue with. Although, thank you so much brother, will keep in mind for the next time I'll be working with arrays!

Answer (score 0):

When your `existingInt` is empty, you will not call `add(i)` to add new item to `existingInt`. So `existingInt` will always be empty according to helper code.

It happens because you will not get in to the for iteration statement.

```
public boolean helper(int i) {
    if (!existingInt.contains(i)) {
        existingInt.add(i);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Actually, you want to do groupBy identity operation on array of integers with counting of occurrences. It is easy to use Java 8 `Streams`:

```
Arrays.stream(array)
    .boxed()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), 
        counting()
     ));
```

You will get `Map<Integer, Long>` with count of each element.

Comment: Dear downvoter, feel free to explain what is wrong with this solution

Comment: Hey brother, I tried to use your helper function, and it actually displayed the correct data, except for one part. For some reason, the number 77 isn't being counted, how come? All the other numbers are displayed correctly, however, 77 isn't being displayed.

Comment: It is not a problem of `77`. May be smth wrong with printing?